# How can i send post requests and manipulate them from the main page with spring boot?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, backend

I am new to Spring boot. I am trying to send a form from the frontend to the backend and display it in the same site. How can I do this?
This is my html.

```
<form action="/" method="post">
 <input class="search" type="text">
<button onclick="sendData()">Send your data</button>
</form>
```

I will display the data on the same site on localhost:8080.

Answer (score 0):

For the backend side, you have to define a controller that will receive the request coming from the frontend.

```
@RestController
public class controller_class{

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> controller_name(@RequestBody String requestBody){
        // logic goes here
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

For the frontend, you have many choices. You can use *React, Angular, etc.*. to send the request to the backend.

However, in your case you seem to be using vanilla JavaScript, in this case you can use ***Ajax*** to make the call to the backend.